# Citation undefined error. Validated .bib file and tried re-running latex and bibtex many times

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

.bib file was generated using Better BibTeX in Zotero. I tried cleaning it with JabRef and it found no issues.
Here is the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%replace "preprint submitted to elsevier" with page number
\usepackage[]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \title{Atmospheric aerosols in the human respiratory system}
    \author{Shimon Chen}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}

    \section{The upper respiratory tract: how aerosols enter the body}
        \subsection{The nose}
            test1 \citep{scott_theoretical_1978}.
    \section{Pre-alveoli lower respiratory tract}
            test2 \cite{breysse_inhalability_1990}.
    \section{Particulates and the blood-air barrier}
    \section{Summary}
\end{document}
\section{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Test}
```

And here is the .bib file:

http://tx.technion.ac.il/~shimi/Latex/Test.bib

And this is the terminal output:

```
> latex Test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty) (./Test.aux)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `scott_theoretical_1978' on page 1 undefined o
n input line 14.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `breysse_inhalability_1990' on page 1 undefine
d on input line 16.


Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[1] (./Test.aux) )
Output written on Test.dvi (1 page, 936 bytes).
Transcript written on Test.log.
```

It doesn't matter how many times I run latex & bibtex. Tried copying to a clean folder. Tried deleting all temporary files and running latex->bibtex->latex->latex. Tried pdflatex. Always the same errors and the document has questions marks instead of references. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
\end{document}
\section{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Test}
```

So you end the document early and the bibliography is never input (as can be seen from the log that you posted)

```
\end{document}
```

should be at the end...

Comment: Wow. That was extremely stupid of me. Thanks!